# Timezone not setted correctly during convesion from java.sql.Timestamp to joda DateTime

Tags: java, scala, datetime, type-conversion, jodatime

I am experimenting some stange issues while trying to convert an object of type `java.sql.Timestamp` into an object of time `org.joda.time.DateTime`. In detail, the Timezone is not set correctly.

Here is my code (scala language):

```
val receptionDate = 
  new DateTime(tuple("RECEPTION_TIMESTAMP").asInstanceOf[Timestamp].getTime(), 
               DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

The `Timestamp` object is read directly from a database table (HBase) and the value showed by SQuirreL client is the following:

```
2015-07-30 00:00:00.0
```

Instead, the `DateTime` object created has the value `2015-07-29 22:00:00.0`. Clearly during the creation of the `DateTime` object it is not used the information of the timezone `DateTimeZone.UTC`, that I am passing to the constructor.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by you are using your ***local Timezone(UTC-2)*** to store date without specifying ***UTC Timezone***, but When you retrieve your date from ***Hbase*** with setting  ***UTC Timezone***. so they are equal time, but are not same `Timezone`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am using the constructor `public DateTime(long instant, DateTimeZone zone)` [doc. here]](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long, org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)). The object should be created using the `DateTimeZone.UTC` that I'm specifing, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, For now `receptionDate` is *UTC* date. but You need to check your date in HBase whether it is `UTC` timezone date. right?

Comment: In HBase the date is stored as a timestamp, so it is in UTC timezone by definition. Sorry, but I'm missing the point. If I've specified the Timezone during the construction of the object, why is it not in UTC?

Comment: Ok, now I've got the things you were trying to saying to me. The problem is the production of the timestamp. The `Timestamp` object is created without specifing the timezone and then it represents the milliseconds starting from 01/01/1970 the date in my timezone, which is UTC-2. If I use this timestamp to build a `DateTime` object specifying the UTC timezone, I will obtain an object that represents a date that misses 2 hour wrt the original. If you modified your answer specifying more in detail the point, I will accept it.

Comment: Cool @riccardo.cardin